# JavaScript Array filter() Method doesn't change not original array really?

Tags: javascript

I have known filter() method doesn't change original array.
However In my code below, It looks like that it is changed...

How come is newArray's size(var) changed?
if filter()method doesn't matter in this situation, when does wordObj give it's value to newArray?

https://jsfiddle.net/s7mL1wtx/2/

```
function wordFrequency(words) {
  // size == frequency
  var newArray = [];
  var wordObj = [];
  words.forEach(function(word) {
    wordObj = newArray.filter(function(o) {
      return o.text == word;
    });
    if (wordObj.length) {
      console.log(word);
      console.log("=====");
      console.log(newArray);
      wordObj[0].size += 1;
    } else {
      newArray.push({
        text: word,
        size: 1
      });
    }
  });
  return newArray;
};

console.log(wordFrequency(["a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a"]))
```

Comment: It's the same throughout.

Comment: You are reassigning `wordObj` at each iteration.

Comment: code shown really doesn't make a lot of sense. Suggest you start over. ALso not really clear what expected results are